# Can get an X Window only on the console or on RDP, but not both at the same time

Tags: nvidia, remote-desktop, xrdp

New to Ubuntu, but I've been around Linux for while.

I built my first Ubuntu box.  Core i5 processor, GeForce GTX1080 graphics.  Running gdm3.

Installed xrdp.

I can be logged in at the console, or I can RDP to the box, but I cannot do both at the same time.  If I'm on the console, my RDP session logs in, but I get a blank screen.  If I log off from the console, I get an X-Window in my RDP but the display on the console switches to "No Signal."

This is driving me crazy because my Raspberry Pi 4 allows me to be logged into both simultaneously.

I've compared xrdp.ini and sesman.ini on both machines, but I can't find any difference.

Is this possibly an NVidia X-Server issue?  Does anyone know how to get simultaneous displays on the console and RDP?

Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu, you cannot simultaneously be connected locally and then remotely using the same user account.  If you are logged in locally and try to remote desktop, you will see a black screen and you will be disconnected immediately.  This is an expected behavior and nvidia should not be considered as the issue.

Possible reason explaining why this would work on a raspberry pi would be that you are using a "older" version of xrdp software.... (version 0.6.x) as older version were allowing simultaneous connections.....

Please check version of xRDP on both systems and provide feedback if required

Hope this help
Till next time
See ya

Answer (score 0):

You can't do both at the same time. Linux is somehow restricted in this regard and it also made it more secure. For RDP of your choice visit [speedrdp](https://speedrdp.com/). 
Nvidia is not the problem, check both your RDP and Linux servers to get the real problem.